# Need to write "U despite of using ngerman babel

Tags: babel

I write a presentation in German language, so I use

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

Now, I want to write `"UTF-8"` but the output looks like that:

[image: scrrenshot]

How can I fix it?

Thank you for your help!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \texttt{"UTF-8"}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `"{}UTF-8"` if you want to keep using shorthands in the rest of your document.

Comment: `\verb|"UTF-8"|` would work as well but might require `fragile` setting on the frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `"` character is defined as a shorthand for `\"` which is why you get the umlaut on the U.  Assuming you are writing umlauts directly in your source anyway, you likely don't need the shorthand, so the easiest solution is to turn it off. You can do this by adding the `shorthands = off` option to `babel`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage[ngerman,shorthands=off]{babel}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \texttt{"UTF-8"}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```